# Is it possible to authenticate in Deezer by server side?

Tags: deezer

Is it possible to authenticate in Deezer by server side?

We are building a website with Deezer player and we don't want to for the end-user to login with Deezer Connect to listen the entire music.

Also, if its not possible authenticate by server side, is it possible to login by Javascript with one "master user" that emulates the end user authentication?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide full-tracks access to your users, they absolutely have to be identified as Deezer Premium users. Therefore, you have to ask them to log in. In the JS SDK, the DZ.login method does all the work for you: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/login.

That's a matter of rights management, Deezer can't provide full-track access to everyone, so the master user solution would not work either.